# Cannot compile u-boot with armv8-rpi4-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

Tags: cross-compiling, u-boot, raspberry-pi4, armv8

I'm facing problems while trying to build the **u-boot** for **Raspberry Pi 4**. The cross-compilation tool I use is ***armv8-rpi4-linux-gnueabihf-gcc***. I get it by using the ***ng-crosstool*** auto toolchain generator. The steps I follow are as follows.

Firstly, inside the ***u-boot*** directory, I declare the `CROSS_COMPILE` and `ARCH` environment variables while changing the `PATH` also:

- `export CROSS_COMPILE=armv8-rpi4-linux-gnueabihf-`
- `export ARCH=arm`
- `export PATH=/home/caglayan/x-tools/armv8-rpi4-linux-gnueabihf/bin:$PATH`

Secondly, I invoke the build process using a board-specific configuration file named `rpi_4_defconfig`.

- `make rpi_4_defconfig`
- `make`

Unfortunately, the build process fails. Below is the simplified terminal output for the process.

```
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18
  CFGCHK  u-boot.cfg
  UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
  CC      lib/asm-offsets.s
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18
  CC      arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18

............. *(Redundant lines removed intentionally.)*

  CC      arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cpu.o
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:36: Error: unexpected character `n' in type specifier
{standard input}:36: Error: bad instruction `b.ne 1b'
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:266: arch/arm/cpu/armv8/cpu.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1784: arch/arm/cpu/armv8] Error 2
```

What do you think that I'm doing wrong? How should I continue to search for a proper solution?

Comment: AFAIK, targets that start "arm" usually indicate 32-bit ARM; for 64-bit the target name is "aarch64".  So you might be using a 32-bit assembler to build 64-bit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the generated toolchain. The ***ng-crosstool*** toolchain generator has many options while generating the proper toolchain you need. If you list the configuration options before invoking the ***ng-crosstool*** you will see that there are two options for the Raspberry Pi 4 development board: `armv8-rpi4-linux-gnueabihf` and `arch64-rpi4-linux-gnu`.

To list the possible configurations, type the following at your `ng-crosstool` directory. The output will show every possible configuration for commonly used systems.

```
bin/ct-ng list-samples
```

The proper configuration is the one with `arch64-` prefix. If you generate the toolchain using that option, the problem will be solved.

*Special thanks to **@NateEldredge**, **@TomRini** and a guy from Linux Turkey Community for giving me some clue :)*

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your compiler.  Please use a standard one for aarch64 from your distribution, or use `tools/buildman/buildman` to download a toolchain from kernel.org for you.

Unrelated to your problem, setting `ARCH=arm` in U-Boot isn't required and in some cases can be actively harmful.  It's not however the culprit in this case as your toolchain isn't seeing `-ffixed-x18` as valid, when it should and must.